# iOS UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark Visible ob every scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a list which I have using as a check boxes. I have enable or disable Check mark on row on select. But when I scroll the list its make mark row after every 10 rows.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (oldCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else
    {
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UItableView` reuses the cell in every scroll so  using condition as per accessory type is not a good practice. You can Create an `NSMutableArray` with selected items and Check as per the Condition below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if ([selected containsIndex:indexPath.row]) {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    } else {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
    // Do the rest of your code
    return cell;
}
```

in `didSelectrowAtindexpath` method you can Add and remove the Selected items.

Comment: Thanks Siba, same thing I have thought and after your reply I have confirmed.

Comment: Another way of doing this is to build a custom UITableViewCell and override the prepareForReuse method, where you can clean up your cell to the initisl state. This helps in case there's much logic behind drawing cell. I did this in my recent work, where a cell could have several badges, and turning them on and off causes cellForRow to be full of codes.

Comment: @Leonardo thanks for your comment, it makes sense. could you able to post some code that you have already done ?

Answer (score 0):

Its because `UITableView` reuses the cell.
So, in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you will have to check for a particular cell (of a particular section and row), if it needs to be checked on, provide the accessory type.

If not needed for that cell, provide accessory type as none.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your logic to set accessory type for cell in  `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and to identify the cell to mark with check mark you can mark the object in the list in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` or manage an array of selected/unselected objects of the list here.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {

        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

        [NSMutableArray addObject:[AnotherMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    } else {

        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

       [NSMutableArray removeObject:[AnotherMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

Also in your viewDidLoad, instantiate you both mutable arrays-

```
yourmutableArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
yourmutableArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: thankX @alloc_iNit. U know, not all programmers are good in designing(me 2) :p